# Default ControlTemplate for Expander

Tags: c#, wpf, controltemplate, expander

can someone (probably using Blend) provide me a working default ControlTemplate for the WPF Expander? I want to do some slight modification but seems that I cannot find a source for a valid template.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is a link to the latest official example in Microsoft documentation, but it differs quite a bit from the default system style: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/expander-styles-and-templates

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have blend, and can help you out. Here is what Blend generated for me.

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Style x:Key="ExpanderRightHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="19"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <TransformGroup.Children>
                                        <TransformCollection>
                                            <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                                        </TransformCollection>
                                    </TransformGroup.Children>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Grid.LayoutTransform>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="circle" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="19" Stroke="DarkGray" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="19"/>
                            <Path x:Name="arrow" Data="M 1,1.5 L 4.5,5 L 8,1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="false" Stroke="#666" StrokeThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,4,0,0" Grid.Row="1" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="arrow" Value="M 1,4.5  L 4.5,1  L 8,4.5"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#FF3C7FB1"/>
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#222"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#FF526C7B"/>
                        <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" TargetName="circle" Value="1.5"/>
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#FF003366"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="ExpanderUpHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="19"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <TransformGroup.Children>
                                        <TransformCollection>
                                            <RotateTransform Angle="180"/>
                                        </TransformCollection>
                                    </TransformGroup.Children>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Grid.LayoutTransform>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="circle" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="19" Stroke="DarkGray" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="19"/>
                            <Path x:Name="arrow" Data="M 1,1.5 L 4.5,5 L 8,1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="false" Stroke="#666" StrokeThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,0,0,0" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="arrow" Value="M 1,4.5  L 4.5,1  L 8,4.5"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#FF3C7FB1"/>
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#222"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#FF526C7B"/>
                        <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" TargetName="circle" Value="1.5"/>
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#FF003366"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="ExpanderLeftHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="19"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <TransformGroup.Children>
                                        <TransformCollection>
                                            <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                                        </TransformCollection>
                                    </TransformGroup.Children>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Grid.LayoutTransform>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="circle" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="19" Stroke="DarkGray" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="19"/>
                            <Path x:Name="arrow" Data="M 1,1.5 L 4.5,5 L 8,1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="false" Stroke="#666" StrokeThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,4,0,0" Grid.Row="1" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="arrow" Value="M 1,4.5  L 4.5,1  L 8,4.5"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#FF3C7FB1"/>
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#222"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#FF526C7B"/>
                        <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" TargetName="circle" Value="1.5"/>
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#FF003366"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="ExpanderHeaderFocusVisual">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border>
                    <Rectangle Margin="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="ExpanderDownHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="19"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Ellipse x:Name="circle" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="19" Stroke="DarkGray" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="19"/>
                        <Path x:Name="arrow" Data="M 1,1.5 L 4.5,5 L 8,1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="false" Stroke="#666" StrokeThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,0,0,0" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="arrow" Value="M 1,4.5  L 4.5,1  L 8,4.5"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#FF3C7FB1"/>
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#222"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#FF526C7B"/>
                        <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" TargetName="circle" Value="1.5"/>
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#FF003366"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="ExpanderStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <DockPanel>
                        <ToggleButton x:Name="HeaderSite" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplateSelector}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource ExpanderHeaderFocusVisual}" FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}" FontStretch="{TemplateBinding FontStretch}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="1" MinWidth="0" MinHeight="0" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Style="{StaticResource ExpanderDownHeaderStyle}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ExpandSite" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Focusable="false" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </DockPanel>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Visible"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ExpandDirection" Value="Right">
                        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Right"/>
                        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="Left"/>
                        <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="{StaticResource ExpanderRightHeaderStyle}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ExpandDirection" Value="Up">
                        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Top"/>
                        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="Bottom"/>
                        <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="{StaticResource ExpanderUpHeaderStyle}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ExpandDirection" Value="Left">
                        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Left"/>
                        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="Right"/>
                        <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="{StaticResource ExpanderLeftHeaderStyle}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<!-- Resource dictionary entries should be defined here. -->
```

Comment: Great thanks. Do you know if this is the Expander of .Net 3.5 or 4? I've heard that they're different.

Comment: My project was set to .NET 4.

Comment: I created a .NET 3.5 project and generated the same style with Blend, and then compared with BeyondCompare and they were identical.

Comment: I had to change the line: <Style x:Key="ExpanderStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Expander}"> to  <Style TargetType="Expander" x:Key="{x:Type Expander}"> to make it work (using VS2008 right now)